# How to redirect to multiple adresses?

Tags: redirect, dns, record

I have a question but it's hard to explain.

How do I redirect shrtsite.com to longsite.com but shrtsite.com/XYZ to anothersite.com?
Something like bitly's branding domains.
The XYZ are random and different every time.

Answer (score 0):

You can write a PHP script that sends out

```
header('Location: http://anothersite.com');
```

depending on the actual path you called the page on. To check what path /XYZ the user called, you can use

$_GET['path']

if you use it together with the htaccess below. And to make all queries to your server go over this script, call it index.php and make a .htaccess file in the root folder, where you also put the index.php file, with the following content

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?path=$1 [NC,L]
```

Comment: Is it possible to do it with A record instead? I don't have access to shrtsite.com and therefore need an easier solution.

Comment: oh, you want to redirect requests from a domain you don't own to another domain? Is it inside a private network or just a single computer? Then you could do something like this using a proxy server maybe?

Comment: Yes, I would like to use it for domains that aren't mine. I don't really understand what you mean by private network or single computer, sorry. I want to redirect all links but the main page to another IP via A record. So all except http://shrtsite.com/. Is that possible?